# Data Transfer time Questions in database design

Tags: database-design

I am preparing for my exams so i am doing pass papers , i am Stuck so i need some help

Suppose that records are stored on a disk with the following characteristics:

- Average Access Motion Time 0.033 see
- Disk Rotation Speed       3600 rev. per minute
- Data Transfer Rate         308,200 bytes per see

(a) What is the expected data transfer time for a randomly accessed record that is 1000
bytes in length?

I got this for A = 0.0445

but I can't do the rest

which is:

If 10 records are stored on a track.

1. What would be the data transfer time for 90 records stored sequentially on the
   same cylinder? [5 marks]
2. What would be the data transfer time for 125 records stored sequentially on
   tracks in different cylinders? [5 marks]
3. What would be the data transfer time for 35 records stored sequentially on tracks in
   different cylinders and each track has fixed read/write heads?
   [5 marks]

Comment: Can Someone get Back to me as soon as possible i can't example for these Question no where on the internet